# Why doing POST throws an exception in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to do a POST like this:

```
    HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
    byte[] bytes = ReadFile(@"my_path");

    var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("FileName", "001.jpeg"));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ConvertToExtension", ".pdf"));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content", Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)));

    HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
    hc.PostAsync("url", content).ContinueWith((postTask) => {
    postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    });
```

but I receive this exception:

> Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.

complaining about this line: `HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);`. For small files it works but I don't understand why for larger ones it doesn't?

When I do POST the **content** can be larger...Then why it complains about URI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use MultipartFormDataContent ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent%28v=vs.110%29 ) instead of FormUrlEncodedContent, which sends your data as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

So even if your using the POST verb, it is still POSTing to a very long url containing your data, hence the error.

> The content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient
>   for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing
>   non-ASCII characters. The content type "multipart/form-data" should be
>   used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and
>   binary data.

See : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1

For a sample, have a look at this answer : [ASP.NET WebApi: how to perform a multipart post with file upload using WebApi HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339877/asp-net-webapi-how-to-perform-a-multipart-post-with-file-upload-using-webapi-ht)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any example how to do this? Is this correct? `MultipartFormDataContent multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            multipartFormDataContent.Add(new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData));`

Comment: @CristianBoariu Updated my answer to link a sample

Comment: @mathieu that example still throw the Exception, since the FormUrlEncodedContent is build

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but I ran into this same issue and found that is is a limitation in the FormUrlEncodedContent class. The reason for the error is that the encoding of the objects is being handled by the `Uri.EscapeDataString()`. [This post explains it on CodePlex.](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1963) I ended up coming up with my own solution to Url Encode using the HTTPUtility class instead.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace Wfm.Net.Http
{
    public class UrlContent : ByteArrayContent
    {
        public UrlContent(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> content)
            : base(GetCollectionBytes(content, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
        }

        public UrlContent(byte[] content, int offset, int count) : base(content, offset, count)
        {
        }

        private static byte[] GetCollectionBytes(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> c, Encoding encoding)
        {
            string str = string.Join("&", c.Select(i => string.Concat(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(i.Key), '=', HttpUtility.UrlEncode(i.Value))).ToArray());
            return encoding.GetBytes(str);
        }
    }


}
```

I wrote a small [article](http://webforwardmedia.com/formurlencodedcontent-invalid-uri-uri-string-long/) on how I implemented it. Hope this helps anyone with the same issues.