# HttpClient: How to upload multiple files at once

Tags: c#, file-upload, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to upload muliple files using [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx).

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
   content.Add(new StreamContent(imageStream), "image", "image.jpg");
   content.Add(new StreamContent(signatureStream), "signature", "image.jpg.sig");

   var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(_profileImageUploadUri, content);
   response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

this only sends mulipart/form-data, but i expected multipart/mixed somewhere in the post.

UPDATE: Ok, i got around.

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    var mixed = new MultipartContent("mixed")
    {
        CreateFileContent(imageStream, "image.jpg", "image/jpeg"),
        CreateFileContent(signatureStream, "image.jpg.sig", "application/octet-stream")
    };

    content.Add(mixed, "files");

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(_profileImageUploadUri, content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}

private StreamContent CreateFileContent(Stream stream, string fileName, string contentType)
{
    var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("file") {FileName = fileName};
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
    return fileContent;
}
```

This looks correct on wire shark. but i do not see the files in my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadProfileImage(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> postedFiles)
{
    if(postedFiles == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    // more code here
}
```

`postedFiles` is still null. Any ideas?

Comment: Sadly, I've running into this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638622/how-to-upload-files-to-asp-net-mvc-4-0-action-running-in-iis-express-with-httpcl/15638623#15638623

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Nailed it. But behaviour is strange.

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    content.Add(CreateFileContent(imageStream, "image.jpg", "image/jpeg"));
    content.Add(CreateFileContent(signatureStream, "image.jpg.sig", "application/octet-stream"));

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(_profileImageUploadUri, content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}

private StreamContent CreateFileContent(Stream stream, string fileName, string contentType)
{
    var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") 
    { 
        Name = "\"files\"", 
        FileName = "\"" + fileName + "\""
    }; // the extra quotes are key here
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);            
    return fileContent;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadProfileImage(IList<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if(files == null || files.Count != 2)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    // more code
}
```

Comment: Wow, you're a genius.  Worked perfectly!

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks. I actually ran into a problem recently using Xamarin, since it fails when putting in the extra quotes. So i had to write my own MultipartFormDataContent class

Comment: @esskar what does the server-side code look like? I can't get this to work.

Comment: For the future references, in case someone can't get it to work in other backend server like Laravel or Express, just add array ```[]``` to the ```Name = "\"files\"''``` => ```Name = "\"files[]\"''``` I stuck with this problem for hours just got solve.

Comment: whats `Stream stream` FileStream, MemoryStream, what ?

Comment: @djack109 does not matter