# Why isn't my MSMVC controller receiving files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, upload, controller, async-await

I'm trying to upload a file to an MSMVC controller using the using HttpClient as so :

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(----);

var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(photoBytes);
fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(DispositionTypeNames.Attachment)
{
    FileName = "test.jpg",
};
content.Add(fileContent);
await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.1.80/upload/upload", content);
```

My controller looks like :

```
[httpPost]
public XmlResult(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

}
```

The controller action fires, I can set a debug point and example the contents of the request.  The Request.Boundry is correct as is Request.TotalBytes but the HttpPostedFileBase is null and Request.Files.Count() is 0...

Any advice on what I'm missing would be great.

Comment: There is no doubt a header youre missing. Have you considered using `WebClient`'s `UploadFile` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906711/httpclient-how-to-upload-multiple-files-at-once

Comment: @Simon Whitehead : I looked at the WebClient implementation but I need to send additional form data which WebClient.UpLoadFile doesn't support.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I tried the code from your link before posting, the result is the same. Somebody mentioned that using a stream might be better than sending a byte[]?

Comment: Have you tried using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see what's going on the wire?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I've gone back and tested with WebClient.UploadFile and the result is the same.  The controller fires the request is the right size but no files in request.files

Comment: @RichardAdams When building an MVC form, you **must** specify the `enctype` as `multipart/form-data` for it to recognise files. Can you add that header into your post somehow and check if the controller picks it up then?