# Upload txt files via Web Service from client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file, model-view-controller

I want to create a web service to upload txt files and store them, this is my service:

```
[WebMethod]
    public bool SaveFiles(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
    {
        try
        {

            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                var InputFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var ServerPath = Path.Combine(string.Format("{0}{1}"), "UploadedFiles", InputFileName);

                file.SaveAs(ServerPath);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return true;
    }
```

and on the client side, who is consuming the service I have in my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
    {
        ViewBag.status = "";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ReferenciaMiServicio.MiServicioSoapClient service = new ReferenciaMiServicio.MiServicioSoapClient();
            var response = service.SaveFiles(files);
            // Falta mandar a¡error cuando la carga no fue valida
            ViewBag.status = "Archivos cargados satisfactoriamente";

        }

        return View();
    }
```

But I get this error in the controller:

> ErrorCS1503   Argumento 1: Cannot convert from
>   'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase[]' a
>   'PruebaMiServicio.ReferenciaMiServicio.HttpPostedFileBase[]'

and exactly highlights the error in files

```
var response = service.SaveFiles(files);
```

You could help me with the solution, this is all C# asp.net

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like, you're getting your project's namespace, which means the datatype `System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase[]` is not getting resolved in the client side, make sure you include `using System.Web;` in client side

Comment: I'd do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906711/httpclient-how-to-upload-multiple-files-at-once rather than trying to call it through generated proxy classes...

Comment: I am using these:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
But it's still the same mistake.