# Https upload MultipartForm returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: c#, forms, file-upload, https, http-status-code-401

I’m trying to upload a [coverity](http://www.coverity.com/)  scan result to coverity.

This is my code:

```
public static void Main( String[] args )
{
    var client = new HttpClient
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 20 )
    };
    var form = new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        { new StringContent( "my tooken" ), "token" },
        { new StringContent( "my email" ), "email" },
        { new StringContent( "1.1.1.1" ), "version" },
        { new StringContent( "Test..." ), "description" }
    };

    var fs = new FileStream( @"cov-int.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read );
    form.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "file", "cov-int.zip");

    var task = client.PostAsync("https://scan.coverity.com/builds?project=Name/Porject", form);
    try
    {
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch ( AggregateException ex )
    {
        throw ex.InnerException;
    }
    var result = task.Result;
    fs.Close();
}
```

The post always end with a failed status (401 unauthorized):

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
  x-request-id: 70dfc119-7d78-47fe-86a7-8505d73225e4
  x-runtime: 1.675468
  x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
  x-content-type-options: nosniff
  Connection: close
  Status: 401 Unauthorized
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 13:01:06 GMT
  Server: Apache
  X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.0.8
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}}
```

I’ve tried to upload the same data, from the same machine to the same server using curl:

```
curl --form token="token" --form email="email" --form file="cov-int.zip" --form version="1.1.1.1" --form description="a message" --insecure https://scan.coverity.com/builds?project=Name/Project
```

Uploading the data with curl works.

What am I doing wrong in my C# code?

Comment: It seems to me your C# code is not posting the HTTP request in the correct format. Look at how to ensure it is a multipart Post HTTP request.

Comment: I can’t find any bad formatted data. Request looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something possibly changed on Coverity's end, since this was working two weeks ago. Based on this other question here [How to upload files to Asp.Net MVC 4.0 action running in IIS Express with HttpClient class included in .Net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638622/how-to-upload-files-to-asp-net-mvc-4-0-action-running-in-iis-express-with-httpcl/15638623#15638623) I've found what I think is the solution.

You need to add extra quotes to your form-data names.

```
var form = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { new StringContent( "my tooken" ), "\"token\"" },
    { new StringContent( "my email" ), "\"email\"" },
    { new StringContent( "1.1.1.1" ), "\"version\"" },
    { new StringContent( "Test..." ), "\"description\"" }
};

form.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "\"file\"", "cov-int.zip");
```

Can't be 100% sure this works since I used up all my attempts for today and will have to wait until tomorrow to see a success response. But I am getting the `"The build submission quota for this project has been reached."` message and not the Access Denied message now.