# multipart/form-data content type request

Tags: c#, http, post, multipartform-data

I am using the below code to post the request with `multipart/form-data` content type but got the exception:

> The remote server returned an error: (532).

How I can solve this?

```
public void request222(string cgid)
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
    nvc.Add("action:WebManager", "OK");
    nvc.Add("cg_id", "" + cgid + "");

    var boundary = "---------------------------DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")";

    //creating request
    var wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://189.126.121.79:8093/API/CCG");
    wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    wr.Method = "POST";
    wr.KeepAlive = true;

    //sending request
    using (var requestStream = wr.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            //params
            const string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
            foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
            {
                requestWriter.Write(boundary);

                requestWriter.Write(String.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]));
            }
            requestWriter.Write("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        }
    }

    //reading response
    try
    {

        using (var wresp = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse())
        {
            if (wresp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (var responseStream = wresp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream == null)

                    using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        string s= responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            throw new ApplicationException("Error Server status code: " + wresp.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Error while uploading file", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a server error, so your request is probably invalid. Whether that's because it's semantically wrong HTTP or a wrong request message according to the API is something you can figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then implementing it on your own, consider using the new API instead: the [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. It has [support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `multipart/form-data`.

For a practical example, see e.g. [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10744043/332528)

Also, it might be better to just use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead, since you don't have any files posted in your request (at least in the example you provided)

Comment: Tried one Http client but got the connection error:
        HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
        var formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                                            {
                                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("action:WebManager", "OK"),
                                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("cg_id", cgid)     });
        MultipartContent content = new MultipartContent();
        content.Add(formData);
        var result = c.PostAsync("http://189.126.121.79:8093/API/CCG", content).Result;

Comment: You should not mix `FormUrlEncodedContent` with `MultipartContent`. See example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15176685/332528